# options for developing an existing web client for mobile

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, cross-platform

we have a flex based app with TCP servers and asmx services that support it and we want to develope a similiar client for iPhone and android (in the future- maybe WP7)
as i see it we have the following options:
1. Cross platform of such kind
2. developing for each mobile 
what are the disadvantages and advantages for each method considering time,syntax learning and future support.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late for the user, but it might be a good reference for the future: [here](http://www.worklight.com/resources/webinars-and-tools/native-web-hybrid-mobile-app-development) you can find a good webinar + slides explaining the three main options (native, hybrid, web). Then towards the end it also expands on some aspects to consider when making the choice.